# Background color of compartmentshape field

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dsl, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

Can anybody tell me how to set the background color of a compartmentshape field programmaticaly? I couldn't find anything to that.

Thx Manuel

Comment: Have a look at the `CompartmentDescription` class; it has a `CompartmentFillColor` property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.diagrams.compartmentdescription(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Hi Matze!

Thx for the tip, but this only allows to set the fill color for a whole compartment. I would like to do that on an item in a compartment.

Comment: If the field is represented by a `ShapeElement` maybe the `BackgroundBrushId` property might be of interest: http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.diagrams.shapeelement.backgroundbrushid(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: No, also not. I have seen this property, but it is a readonly property. I think there is no way to change the background color easily.